# Stop interval when session times out

Tags: angular, spring, session, oauth, intervals

I have an angular 8 project that uses a few interval to refresh data. These interval are very small (between 500 and 2000ms) because the data needs to be refreshed very quickly.

when the home component is initialized, a ping interval is started. This ping interval checks for a valid session every two seconds:

```
private ping() {
    if (this.isAuthenticated()) {
      this.initIntervalsIfNecessary();
    } else {
      clearInterval(this.daxInterval);

    if(this.daxIndexSubscription) {
         this.daxIndexSubscription.unsubscribe();
      }

      if (this.daxInterval) {
        this.daxInterval = null;
      }
   }
}
```

The idea is that the system checks for a valid session. If the user is not properly authenticated anymore that interval is removed:

```
private initIntervalsIfNecessary() {
    if (!this.daxInterval) {
        this.daxInterval = setInterval(() => {
            this.daxIndexSubscription = this.daxIndexService
              .getCurrentDaxIndex()
              .subscribe((res: HttpResponse<DaxIndex>) => this.onSuccess(res.body), (res: HttpErrorResponse) => this.onError(res.message));
          }, 500);
     }
}
```

This works perfectly fine if the user logs out manually.

However, if the session times out and the user keep the browser open, the intervals continue. They are properly blocked on the server side, but because the intervals are so small, my log gets flooded:

```
[2020-04-13 08:15:09] WARN 5885 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.z.problem.spring.common.AdviceTraits   : Unauthorized: Full authentication is required to access this resource
[2020-04-13 08:15:09] WARN 5885 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.z.problem.spring.common.AdviceTraits   : Unauthorized: Full authentication is required to access this resource
[2020-04-13 08:15:09] WARN 5885 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.z.problem.spring.common.AdviceTraits   : Unauthorized: Full authentication is required to access this resource
[2020-04-13 08:15:09] WARN 5885 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.z.problem.spring.common.AdviceTraits   : Unauthorized: Full authentication is required to access this resource
[2020-04-13 08:15:10] WARN 5885 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.z.problem.spring.common.AdviceTraits   : Unauthorized: Full authentication is required to access this resource
```

The stack was built using jHipster, using oAuth for authentication.

So my question is: how can I make sure, I can stop the interval if the session times out? Thanks for any hints.

Comment: I guess you get an error response from the api? in that callback clear the interval?

Comment: Yes, i get a 401 error upon timeout. It's flooding my browser's console log as well.

Comment: Cool, could you share the code for `this.onSuccess` and `this.onError` please

Comment: Sure: 

private onError(errorMessage: string) {
    this.jhiAlertService.error(errorMessage, null, null);
  }

  private onSuccess(data: DaxIndex) {
    this.dax = data.price;
    this.notifyDaxIndex(this.dax);
  }

I'm gonna add an additional call to clear interval if the error message contains a 401 or connection refused message

Comment: Yup, thats the missing piece, in the `onError` method, clear the interval

Comment: I'll have a look, thanks a lot!